# How to draw the static part of the combobox

Tags: winapi, combobox, mfc, custom-draw

I have a custom drawn combobox with style `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` and `CBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE` I can draw the items of the dropdownlist ok but whe user select an item it is drawn in the combobox static part [the part of combo that stay visible after selecting item and show the selection], I want to give it a custom text like in the following image

[image]

But I can't determine it I found a code like this

```
    if(DrawItemStruct.CtlType == ODT_COMBOBOX)//the static part of the combo
        DrawComboText(pDC, DrawItemStruct.itemID, &DrawItemStruct.rcItem);
    else//the rest items
    {
        // Copy the text of the item to a string
        char sItem[256];
        GetString(sItem, DrawItemStruct.itemID);
        biDrawText(pDC, sItem, -1, &DrawItemStruct.rcItem, f | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
    }
```

but when I used it I get all the items has `CtlType == ODT_COMBOBOX`, when I debugged the above code It return `ODT_COMBOBOX` for the static part, and for items of the drop down list it return `ODT_LISTBOX`.

I want to know how to fix this problem, **how to detect that I'm drawing the static part or a regular item in the dropdown list?**

Comment: Unclear to me. You seem to answer your own question: `ODT_COMBOBOX` for text in static control. `ODT_LISTBOX` for text from a Listbox item. That, or I didn't understand your question.

Comment: That is what I took from  other source code but the ODT_LISTBOX never sent it was always ODT_COMBOBOX, in the source that I copied from it works fine, I don't know what I missed

Comment: I deal with the static portion by checking whether `DrawItemStruct.itemID == -1`

Comment: @user1793036 : that is OK if there is no selected item from the combo when you select item say item index = 2, then when the list is closed and while drawing the static part the itemID == 2.

Answer (score 1):

I just check the state for ODS_COMBOBOXEDIT. If ifthe dcumentation says that this flag is set for the edit Control, it works for the drop down list to.

I have checked combo box implementation like you that works in the sane way.

```
bool bDrawStaticControl = (pDIS->itemState & ODS_COMBOBOXEDIT)!=0;
```