# How to detect ODS_COMBOBOXEDIT in custom styled owner draw TComboBox

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles, tcombobox

Using Delphi 10.3:

In an owner-drawn `TComboBox` with `Style=csOwnerDrawFixed`, I want the owner drawn items in the DropDown list to be different from the static part of the combo. To discriminate between the two cases, I check for `odComboBoxEdit` in the `State` parameter, as described here:

[How to draw the static part of the combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267320/)

```
procedure TStylePanel.TargetArrowComboDrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  if (odComboBoxEdit in State) then
  begin
    // Paint static control
  end
  else
  begin
    // Paint item in dropped down list
  end;
end;
```

This works well as long as there's no custom VCL style active. However, with a custom style, this no longer works reliably. Checking the source in `Vcl.StdCtrls.pas` for `TComboBoxStyleHook`, it seems to me that the cause is in this combination:

```
procedure TComboBoxStyleHook.WMPaint(...)
procedure TComboBoxStyleHook.DrawItem(...)
```

When there's no edit handle (which is the case for `csOwnerDrawFixed`), `DrawItem()` assembles a `TDrawItemStruct` that will *never* contain `ODS_COMBOBOXEDIT`, as a result the `CN_DRAWITEM` handler will never have `odComboBoxEdit` set.

I could override `TComboBoxStyleHook`, but I'd need a way to detect if the item is the static item or an item in the list.

As a workaround, I check for `Combo.DroppedDown`, but that's not the same: even when dropped down, I want the static part to be painted differently than the items in the list.

So the question is, how can I detect (in the custom draw handler or in the style hook) that the custom drawn item is the static area rather than an item in the list?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it working by adding a stylehook for TComboBox that unconditionally includes `ODS_COMBOBOXEDIT`. The assumption is that `TComboBoxStyleHook.DrawItem` is **only** called by `TComboBoxStyleHook.WMPaint` when it needs to custom draw the static item, the drop down list is not handled there. There seem to be no unwanted side effects.

```
type
  TComboBoxStyleHookFix = class(TComboBoxStyleHook)
  strict protected
    procedure DrawItem(Canvas: TCanvas; Index: Integer; const R: TRect; Selected: Boolean); override;
  end;

procedure TComboBoxStyleHookFix.DrawItem(Canvas: TCanvas; Index: Integer; const R: TRect; Selected: Boolean);
var
  DIS: TDrawItemStruct;
begin
  FillChar(DIS, SizeOf(DIS), 0);
  DIS.CtlType := ODT_COMBOBOX;
  DIS.CtlID := GetDlgCtrlID(Handle);
  DIS.itemAction := ODA_DRAWENTIRE;
  DIS.hDC := Canvas.Handle;
  DIS.hwndItem := Handle;
  DIS.rcItem := R;
  DIS.itemID := Index;
  DIS.itemData := SendMessage(ListHandle, LB_GETITEMDATA, 0, 0);
  if (Control is TComboBox) and (TComboBox(Control).Style = csOwnerDrawFixed) then
    DIS.itemState := ODS_COMBOBOXEDIT;
  if Selected then
    DIS.itemState := DIS.itemState or ODS_FOCUS or ODS_SELECTED;

  SendMessage(Handle, WM_DRAWITEM, Handle, LPARAM(@DIS));
end;

procedure InitComboStyleHookFix();
begin
  TCustomStyleEngine.RegisterStyleHook(TComboBox, TComboBoxStyleHookFix);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the edit control, TCustomCombobox does all the work in

procedure CNDrawItem(var Message: TWMDrawItem); message CN_DRAWITEM;

It never calls WM_DRAWITEM, so one solution is to override that method (CnDrawItem).